# how to display empty wordpress page with template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, filter

I am newbie to wordpress programming.

Page A's content is empty, but it is using a template php code that displays the HTML content instead.

From another page B's template php code, I do the apply_filters to display what page A displays, but it shows empty page! It does not display what page A's template php displays!

```
$args = array('name' => $slug, 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'numberposts' => 1);

$my_post = get_posts($args);
if( $my_post ) {
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $my_post[0]->post_content);
}
```

I want to display whatever the template A php displays.

THANKS

Comment: You can create different templates for different conditions and select each templates for each page in back end

Comment: Your question is not clear please give clear specification and detail

Comment: I edited the description to be more clear

Comment: developerme - please show me how to do that. thanks